# Xcode Openframeworks - ld: library not found for -lLeap

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, openframeworks, leap-motion

I have this problem "ld: library not found for -lLeap" when running on Xcode. But I've add the addon "ofxLeapMotion2".

```
<pre>Ld bin/isosphereMiDiDebug.app/Contents/MacOS/isosphereMiDiDebug normal i386
    cd /Users/yuanshq/Documents/Openframework/apps/myApps/isosphereMiDi
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.6
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -L/Users/yuanshq/Documents/Openframework/apps/myApps/isosphereMiDi/bin -F/Users/yuanshq/Documents/Openframework/apps/myApps/isosphereMiDi/bin -F/Users/yuanshq/Documents/Openframework/apps/myApps/isosphereMiDi/../../../libs/glut/lib/osx -filelist /Users/yuanshq/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/isosphereMiDi-cxmrshpintlivwhfnjzrhmgsuevc/Build/Intermediates/isosphereMiDi.build/Debug/isosphereMiDi.build/Objects-normal/i386/isosphereMiDiDebug.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -dead_strip ../../../libs/poco/lib/osx/PocoCrypto.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/osx/PocoData.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/osx/PocoDataODBC.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/osx/PocoDataSQLite.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/osx/PocoFoundation.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/osx/PocoNet.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/osx/PocoNetSSL.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/osx/PocoUtil.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/osx/PocoXML.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/osx/PocoZip.a ../../../libs/tess2/lib/osx/tess2.a ../../../libs/glew/lib/osx/glew.a ../../../libs/cairo/lib/osx/cairo-script-interpreter.a ../../../libs/cairo/lib/osx/cairo.a ../../../libs/cairo/lib/osx/pixman-1.a ../../../libs/fmodex/lib/osx/libfmodex.dylib ../../../libs/rtAudio/lib/osx/rtAudio.a ../../../libs/openssl/lib/osx/crypto.a ../../../libs/openssl/lib/osx/ssl.a ../../../libs/glfw/lib/osx/libglfw3.a ../../../libs/FreeImage/lib/osx/freeimage.a ../../../libs/freetype/lib/osx/freetype.a -stdlib=libstdc++ -framework Accelerate -framework QTKit -framework GLUT /Users/yuanshq/Documents/Openframework/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/osx/openFrameworksDebug.a -framework AGL -framework ApplicationServices -lLeap -framework AudioToolbox -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreServices -framework OpenGL -framework QuickTime -framework AppKit -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreMIDI -framework CoreVideo -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/yuanshq/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/isosphereMiDi-cxmrshpintlivwhfnjzrhmgsuevc/Build/Intermediates/isosphereMiDi.build/Debug/isosphereMiDi.build/Objects-normal/i386/isosphereMiDiDebug_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/yuanshq/Documents/Openframework/apps/myApps/isosphereMiDi/bin/isosphereMiDiDebug.app/Contents/MacOS/isosphereMiDiDebug
```

ld: library not found for -lLeap

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks!!

Comment: OK, so what's the exact filename of the library?

Comment: @trojanfoe It is ofxLeapMotion2, a wrapper for the Leap Motion SDK.

Comment: No, I'd like to know the exact name of the file (for example `libLeapMotion2.a` or `libLeap.dylib`).

Comment: @trojanfoe I think it is libLeap.dylib, since this is the only library file I can find in that addon.

Comment: OK so the `-lLeap` command line option is correct; the `-L` must be missing/wrong.

Comment: @trojanfoe So, how can I fix this problem? Can u please show me some specific procedures that I can follow?

Comment: I don't know the procedures.  You are probably better off asking on the openFrameworks forum.

Comment: What version of the Leap Motion SDK does this ofxLeapMotion2 wrapper use? We dropped support for libstdc++ in version 2.27 -- and even then you had to use a different version of libLeap.dylib. Does ofxLeapMotion2 require libstdc++, or is that a setting you chose (or defaulted to)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cocoapods is because you need to open `.xcworkspace`.

- Close the Xcode;
- Run `pod install` and `pod update`;
- Open the new `.xcworkspace`;
- `Clean` and `Build` your Project;
- Now, you are able to `run` normally.